# How can I understand that at t<0 the DC source is disconnected?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]Fundamental of electric circuits by Sadiku at page 264 in the example 7.5 how come the DC voltage source is disconnected when the circuit is in t<0 position ?????

please help this is bugging me out :(

Comment: Could you provide more information, perhaps a picture of the example.

Comment: i have provided the photo of that

Comment: Could you clarify your question, from the picture the switch is open at t<0 and the switch closes a t=0. The DC source is connected the whole time. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: I agree with@vini_i, the source is clearly not disconnected at T<0 otherwise the circuit would not have reached steady state by T=0 and the inductor would not be a short circuit as shown in fig 7-20(a).

Comment: brothers, at t<0 it says the switch is open......in that case is figure 7.20(a) is possible ?? am i missing anything here.....may be um mistaken at any part but can you please tell me where

Comment: I don't see any issue in fig 7.20a nor in 7.20b, anything is as described in text. Where the problem is? No source is diconnected, rather it is bypassed by switch at time t>=0 fig 7.20b

Comment: Questions such as this assume that the switch has been open (or closed) for a long time. The switch is then closed (or opened) and at that precise moment the clock starts ticking. So t=0 is the instant of operating the switch and t>0 means the values of time after operating the switch. t<0 is the time before the switch was operated.

Answer (score 2):

At time t<0 the switch has been open for a long time, and the circuit looks like figure 7.19.  Note in that figure the source is connected in series with the 2 ohm resistor.

Since the circuit has been like that for a long time it has reached steady-state.  There's no change in current through the inductor, and since V=L*di/dt (where di/dt is zero) the voltage across the inductor is zero.  The inductor can be replaced by a short for t<0, as shown in 7.20(a).

Once the switch is closed at t=0 currents will now start to change and the inductor's response to that is now important.  However, since you solved the circuit at T just less than zero you know the initial condition for the current in the inductor.

The effect of the source is removed from the right hand side of the circuit by the switch, which is a short across the source and its 2 ohm resistor. 5A will flow from the source through the 2A resistor, but that has no impact on the circuit to the right of the short, as shown in figure 7.20(b)

Answer (score 0):

> how come the DC voltage source is disconnected when the circuit is in
>   t<0 position

There is no problem with the switch closing at t=0. It's just an exercise in understanding how the already-built-up current in an inductor decays to zero when the energy from the power source is diverted.